# Tweepy, API Twitter , api.source not found (changes?)

Tags: python, api, twitter, tweepy

Hi StackOverflow community, I have a query that I am completely unaware of and it is regarding the API 1.1 of Twitter, Tweepy and Python. It turns out that doing my little analysis on devices used, given a certain HastTag, I see that the part within the related Json (api.source) in certain accounts comes out completely without data, including mine when I send a post from my app. what happened ? Is this option going to disappear? Is anyone informed about it? Thank you !

```
# define streaming class
```

class TweetStreamListener(StreamListener):

```
# on success
def on_data(self, status):
    # convert string to JSON
    data = json.loads(status)

    # extract relevant information
    description = data['user']['description']
    loc = data['user']['location']
    text = data['text']
    coords = data['coordinates']
    name = data['user']['screen_name']
    user_created = data['user']['created_at']
    followers = data['user']['followers_count']
    id_str = data['id_str']
    created = data['created_at']
    retweets = data['retweet_count']
    bg_color = data['user']['profile_background_color']
    idTweet = data['id']
    source = data['source'] 
    print(name)
    print(text)
    print('Source: ', source)


    return True

# on failure
def on_error(self, status):
    print(status)
```

Results :

[Results 'Source' blank New features API ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzBa1.png)

Comment: What did you already try? What concrete issues are you facing?
Thanks for considering [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Can you please share your code? What error are you seeing? this is impossible to help with based on what you've shared so far.